# Remote Repo name changed in Github, but not reflecting in Local Repo with Git fetch

Tags: git, github, fetch, git-remote

- Old Repo name : Old_repo_name
- New Repo name : new_repo_name

Tried below commands

```
git remote set-url origin <new_url_after_repo_change>
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Verified the new URL with below command.

> git remote -v

Remote URL updated. But root folder name of repo didn't change

Comment: Have you tried renaming the folder yourself?

Comment: No. I am looking for any git command which does the work.

Comment: Adding to that, we cant change a folder name when files are being user under it.

Comment: I don't think the folder that contains the Git repo is controlled by Git.

Comment: here folder name is repo name only not the parent folder name of repo

Comment: As far as I know, the local "repo name" is .git. Always. It is not something you can change. So that can't be what you mean. Presumably, you are expecting to see something change in your working tree then? You probably have the commits from the new repo locally now. I would try "git branch" to see what branches you have available. If that's not helpful, you can probably do "git checkout -b myname hash" with the hash of the commit at head in the new remote repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just to answer my own question, which I posted 2 years back, there is no relation between git local
> repo root folder name and git remote repo name. When you clone a repo,
> local repo  root folder will be same as remote repo name. Both local
> repo root folder name and remote repo name are independent of each
> other. When you change local repo root folder name, It doesn't impact
> the remote repo name even when you push the code. Similarly changing the remote repo name doesn't impact the local repo root folder name in your machine.

So, you can create a new empty folder with any name and make it a git repo with git init.
You can point it to any remote repo. The local repo folder name and remote repo name needn't not be same. The same local repo can be pushed to multiple remote repos by adding the corresponding remote URLs.